# CiviVolunteer Profile nr. 14 Hardcoded?

Tags: profile, civivolunteer

Installed civicrm 4.6.22 with CiviVolunteer 4.6-2.0.2.
When I wanted to add a project, I got the message: ID 14 of profile is not found.
Upgraded to 4.6-2.1.2 but same problem.

After some searching I found out there was indeed no profile 14. When I copied the profile 'Volunteer Sign Up' with Profile ID 25 and saved is as Profile 14 the problem was solved.

Is it possible that the number of the profile is hard coded instead of taking the next free number in the list of profiles?

My problem was solved, but thought it good to let you know, in case you have the same issue.